# Align/Margins in CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, alignment

Why does the following seemingly do nothing?

```
    <style>
    form {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    h1 {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        color : #2265FF;
    }
    </style>
<body>
<h1>Please type in the text to be converted!</h1>
<form> ... </form>
```

Obviously, I have some more HTML to go along with this.

Is there a better way to do this in CSS3?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do? more info pls.

Comment: What you wanna exactly do? Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Probably would be a good idea to show the HTML that this is being applied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS3 you can do:

```
form, h1 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to support older browsers, you need to specify a width:

```
form, h1 {
    width: 500px
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but it's actually better if you apply it to a parent container...

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}

<div class="container">
  <h1></h1>     
  <form></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you better use `text-align:center` instead because `<form>` and `<h1>` will set its width to `100%` by default.